# Cannot get Calabash-Android 0.4.18 to work with Ruby 2.0.0

Tags: android, ruby, testing, cucumber, calabash

My colleagues successfully used this combination to write our tests and they work fine:

```
cucumber (1.2.5)
calabash-android (0.4.3)
gherkin (2.11.8)
ruby (1.8.7)
```

However, we're upgrading and the tests do not work with this combination:

```
cucumber (1.3.10)
ruby (2.0.0)
gherkin (2.12.2)
calabash-android (0.4.18)
```

I receive the following errors:

Given my app is running

Given I set `TestSessionToken` to `hrn_token`

Then I wait for 10 seconds

Given I wait to see text "Welcome"

```
**Step unsuccessful: Time out while waiting for text:Welcome (RuntimeError)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:66:in timeout'
./features/step_definitions/calabash_steps.rb:41:in/^I wait to see text "([^\"]*)"$/'
features/shared_features/010_welcomescreen/000_test.feature:13:in `Given I wait to see text "Welcome"'**
```

On further tests i begin to receive `KeepAliveDisconnected`/`Timeout` errors:

Given I wait to see text "Welcome"

```
**HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected (HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:66:in timeout'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:97:intimeout'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:66:in timeout'
./features/step_definitions/calabash_steps.rb:41:in/^I wait to see text "([^\"]*)"$/'
features/shared_features/010_welcomescreen/999_moveon.feature:9:in `Given I wait to see text "Welcome"'**
```

Thanks